# How to extract a part of string starting with a particular string in java

Tags: java

I have a string in java

```
String s="a=one b=two c=three d=four e=five"
```

and i want to print the value of c i.e; three.

I took StringTokenizer and i got.

```
a=one
b=two
c=three
d=four
e=five
```

and i want to print the value of c i.e; three.

Comment: You can get the answer from any one of the answers available here, but just small comment; don’t use regression for such simple kind of problems. 

Otherwise you will have two problems not only one.

Comment: @MohamedSweelam How is this question using regression?

Comment: Check Tim Biegeleisen answer @NomadMaker, by the way, this is a typo, I mean regular expression.

Comment: Loop through each token `t` returned by `StringTokenizer`, test with `t.startsWith("c=")`; if true, your value is `t.substring(2)`; otherwise, look at next token.

Answer (score 0):

For a one line solution, you could use `String#replaceAll`:

```java
String input = "a=one b=two c=three d=four e=five";
String cValue = input.replaceAll(".*\\bc=(.+?)\\b.*", "$1");
System.out.println("c: " + cValue);
```

This prints:

```
c: three
```

If you want to go the route of splitting to an array of key value pairs, then consider using streams:

```
String input = "a=one b=two c=three d=four e=five";
String cValue = Arrays.stream(input.split("\\s+"))
                    .filter(x -> "c".equals(x.split("=")[0]))
                    .map(x -> x.split("=")[1])
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())
                    .get(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you know that the letter values are unique, you can convert it to Map, using streams. I wrote a quick method in test package for you

```
    @Test
    public void test() {
        String s="a=one b=two c=three d=four e=five";

        Map<String, String> myMap = Arrays.stream(s.split(" ")).collect(
                Collectors.toMap(
                        key -> key.split("=")[0],
                        value -> value.split("=")[1]
                )
        );

        System.out.println(myMap.get("c"));
    }
```

How does it work?
It takes your string, splits it first by spaces - as a result you end up with the List of Strings. Then you process it as a stream, use static factory method toMap from Collectors class and split key and value by "=", creating a map (first value as a key, second converted to value) based on this. Then you can get any key value pair You want

Answer (score -1):

Iterate the returned object from `StringTokenizer` and use the `split` function to split with `=` character,

`split()` will return array, check the 0th index with any character you want (in this case 'c'), if equal, return the 1st index

```
while (st1.hasMoreTokens()) {
      String s = st1.nextToken();
      String a[] = s.split("=");
      if(a[0) == "c") {
        System.out.println(a[1]);
      }
}
```